# How do you use an html helper in Razor without closing an included <li> tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using the following helper to help me generate links:

```
@helper BuildLink(string name, string action, string controller)
    {
    var url = Url.Action(action, controller);
    bool isActive = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Equals(url, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    <li class="@(isActive ? "current" : String.Empty)"><a href="@(url)">@name</a></li>
}
```

It works great.  The problem is, I need to close my "li" tag at a different point in my document.  If I delete the "closing li" part of my helper, I get an error message when I try to look at the view:

Parser Error Message: The helper block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

Is there a way around having to include this closing "li" tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you place a @: before any tag. It avoids the closing tag validation of razor
e.g.

```
@:<li>
```

Comment: Perfect, did not know that and was struggling to find the appropriate documentation.  Thank you.

Comment: Aditionally, you can also use `@:` when razor thinks you are typing syntax when you are really typing html or text.